# In node with Q, something between 'Spread' and 'allSettled'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Something I find very useful in Q is the `Q.allSettled` function for array of promises that allow you to handle failure cases without having a `fail` handler.

On the other hand right now I would need to use `Q.spread` function to spread some promises and some params to the `then` handler without getting to the `fail` handler if some promises fails.

A possible solution is the one suggested in Q's docu:

```
q.allSettled([saveToDisk(), saveToCloud(), 12345])
.spread(function (disk, cloud, somenum) {
    console.log('somenum: ' + somenum.value);
    console.log("saved to disk:", disk.state === "fulfilled");
    console.log("saved to cloud:", cloud.state === "fulfilled");
});
```

but I was wondering, do the library provides anything similar, like `Q.spreadSettled`? 
If not, is it planned? Am I the only one who think it could be a good idea to have something like that?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: 10.35, why? Mine is more of a Q-related question, but I guess you want to propose other libraries, right?

Comment: Well, JavaScript has native spread, `Q.spread` is just a shim for it. Q is an old library and I would not use it, but that's not what I was implying. Is node 4.0.0 an option?

Comment: Not really, and ATM Q is pretty mandatory. Out of curiosity, what's your proposal?

Comment: Can you please post one of the working workarounds? I still don't really get what you are looking for. How is it different from `Q.allSettled([…]).spread(function(…){…})`?

Comment: @bncc well, since 2013 bluebird pretty much does anything Q does only significantly better and with newer APIs. Anyway, can you show us some code illustrating the problem? ES2015, supported in modern node, lets you spread arbitrary functions.

Comment: my first idea was @Bergi's suggestion (`Q.allSettled([…]).spread(function(…){…})`), I was just wondering why there weren't any API doing the same, something like `Q.spreadSettled([...])`. I would also point out that I'm not talking about any problem or any difficulty, I was just curious

Comment: @bncc: Where would `spreadSettled` take the callback? No, there is no such method in Q, and notice that most static methods are just convenience wrappers for method calls.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense because it's not the responsibility of `Q.allSettled([...])` to decide how the resolved values are passed, it's up to the method chained to it.

`Q.allSettled([...])` can be followed by both:

```
.spread(function(comma, separated, resolved, values){...})
```

and

```
.then(function(arrayOfResolvedValues){...})
```

Without chaining a method, you would never see the resolved values of `Q.spreadSettled([...])`